# access a controllers variable or method from within the views subview class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, parent, viewcontroller

Good Evening,
Here is the problem, [self.view addSubview:pauseView];
before the pauseView is loaded over the current view a BOOL isPaused is turned to false and then the subview appears. i am trying to change the value of the variable to false from withing the pauseview but since it's not on the current class i am unable to do this.
I know that this topic is already covered in stackoverflow but i still cannot solve my problem. If i'm able to solve this problem, it will solve the same kind of problem in 3 others apps of mine.

Sincerely,
Sonic555gr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define isPaused as a property in the class that defines isPaused (let's call it MasterView):

```
// inside MasterView.h
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isPaused;
```

Then make your subview pauseView a custom UIView subclass (let's call it PauseView) and in this subclass define a property called master of type MasterView:

```
// inside PauseView.h
@property (nonatomic,assign) MasterView *master
```

Then when you alloc/init your pauseView just set this property:

```
// somewhere inside MasterView.m
PauseView *pauseView = [[PauseView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
pauseView.master=self;
```

Finally in your PauseView class, in the point of your code where you want to change the isPaused property, do this:

```
// somewhere in PauseView.m
master.isPaused=YES
```

Comment: I see now that if i pass a reference to an instance of my main controller to one of its subviews then i can manipulate any variable! You cleared my head and for that i thank you! :D

Comment: ok, great; but don't insist on this model, try to keep separate the view and the controller, and remember that the controller must control the views and not viceversa; so I hope this in an exception in your code but not the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You really should have a think about your architecture and try to move your application logic from away from UIViews and back to the controller (i.e. delegates might be a good option but impossible to know without seeing more of your code and what you are trying to achieve).

If you insist on manipulating the variable from the UIView, you need to pass a reference of your viewController to the pauseView when you initialise it.

So in your PauseView class, you would create a custom initialiser:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andViewController:(id)vc {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
       // Any other custom initialisation here
   }
}
```